# how to make enemy randomly change direction after contact with block

Tags: python, pygame, collision

oops i wanted to delete it but it wont let me, sorry,

Answer (score 2):

It really wants to change direction to a non-colliding way.  The `movedirection()` knows which way it was traveling, so this direction can be removed from the choices.

```
def movedirection(self, x, y):
    next_movement = ( x, y )  # no change
    self.rect.x = self.rect.x + x
    self.rect.y = self.rect.y + y

    # If you collide with a wall, move out based on velocity
    for block in block_list:
        if self.rect.colliderect(block.rect):
            if x > 0:       # Moving right Hit the left side of the wall
                self.rect.right = block.rect.left
                directions = [(-2,0),(0,-2),(0,2)]  # L, D, U
            elif x < 0:       # Moving left Hit the right side of the wall
                self.rect.left = block.rect.right
                directions = [( 2,0),(0,-2),(0,2)]  # R, D, U
            if y > 0:       # Moving down Hit the top side of the wall
                self.rect.bottom = block.rect.top
                directions = [(-2,0),(2,0),(0,-2)]  # L, R, D
            elif y < 0:       # Moving up Hit the bottom side of the wall
                self.rect.top = block.rect.bottom
                directions = [(-2,0),(2,0),(0,2)]   # L, R, U     

            # pick a new random direction that does not re-collide
            next_movement = random.choice( directions )

    # The enemy either continues, or turned
    return next_movement
```

Obviously the movement logic needs to change to incorporate the return result:

```
def move(self, x, y):
    return self.movedirection( x, y )

def movmethod(self,godirection,changedirection):
    while True:
        godirection = move( godirection )
```

But the `movmethod()` still has a nasty infinite loop (it never returns).  I would model the movement on the way PyGame Sprite classes typically hand this, with an `update()` function.  This handles the movement, and bitmap changes etc.

```
def update( self ):
    x, y = self.godirection  # NOTE: now a member variable
    self.rect.x = self.rect.x + x
    self.rect.y = self.rect.y + y

    # If you collide with a wall, move out based on velocity
    for block in block_list:
        if self.rect.colliderect( block.rect ):
            if x > 0:       # Moving right Hit the left side of the wall
                self.rect.right = block.rect.left
                directions = [(-2,0),(0,-2),(0,2)]  # L, D, U
            elif x < 0:       # Moving left Hit the right side of the wall
                self.rect.left = block.rect.right
                directions = [( 2,0),(0,-2),(0,2)]  # R, D, U
            if y > 0:       # Moving down Hit the top side of the wall
                self.rect.bottom = block.rect.top
                directions = [(-2,0),(2,0),(0,-2)]  # L, R, D
            elif y < 0:       # Moving up Hit the bottom side of the wall
                self.rect.top = block.rect.bottom
                directions = [(-2,0),(2,0),(0,2)]   # L, R, U     

            # pick a new random direction that does not re-collide
            self.godirection = random.choice( directions )
```

Call `update()` in the main-loop.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help, i tried this however using x,y = self.godirection  did not work so i tried a different method, however the problem with this is that it when function is called, it will change direction permanently    .I did this by adding self direction = random at start of function    @Kingsley